# How to notify the recipient user when activity is updated proactively in MS Teams Bot

Tags: .net-core, bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, chatbot

I have created an MS Teams bot, which sends proactive messages to the team members. I also update these messages. I am doing this using ConnectorClient. When I send the message user gets a notification popup and the bot chat window is highlighted showing the new message is received. I want this same behavior when I update this message. The message is getting updated properly but the recipient is not notified.

Here is my code to update the activity. I tried a few things i.e. setting the DeliveryMode property of the activity but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
var act = MessageFactory.Text("updated Text");
act.Id = ActivityId;
act.DeliveryMode = DeliveryModes.Notification;
await connectorClient.Conversations.UpdateActivityAsync(ConversationId, ActivityId, act);
```

Comment: Notifying the recipient user when activity is updated proactively in MS Teams Bot doesn't seem to be feasible. We referred: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/update-and-delete-bot-messages?tabs=dotnet#update-messages